# Generics - how to return a Map of T?

Tags: java, generics

```
class MyObject{}
class Human extends MyObject{}

public ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, <T extends MyObject>> get(Class<T> clazz, Object... vars){
    //...
}

//use the get() with
ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Human> mapOfAllAdams = get(Human.class, "Adam");
```

However, the return value `ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, <T extends MyObject>>` gives compilation error, but `<T extends MyObject>T` is ok. What should I write instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes

```
class MyObject{}
class Human extends MyObject{}

public <T extends MyObject> ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, T> get(Class<T> clazz, Object... vars){
    //...

    return null;
}

//use the get() with
void hello(){
    ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Human> x = get(Human.class, "Adam");
}
```

I declared `<T extends MyObject>` before the return type and also added a variable x to hold the return value of the `get` function.